# How do I edit custom close reasons?

Tags: support, moderator-tools, custom-close-reasons

There's a typo in one of our custom Off Topic reasons and I need to edit it, but I don't see an edit button:

[image]

How do I edit an already active close reason? Do I have to deactivate the existing one then add a new, corrected custom reason, or can I edit it after deactivating it and reactivate it or what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't.

Custom off-topic reasons are editable *only until they are approved* - after that, they're frozen. This is to prevent a reason from being changed into a completely different reason after it has already been reviewed or especially after it has been *used on the site*.

Reasons can always be deactivated however, so you can create a new reason, edit it until you're happy with it, and then get another moderator to deactivate the old one and approve your new one.

Comment: You guys just *had* to miss an i in "pictorially" so we'd have to do all this, didn't you

Comment: Wouldn't making them editable be a workable solution? It should be possible to teach mods not to completely change the reasons, and you can always poke them with a sharp stick if they do it anyway. Deactivating doesn't work retroactively, but in cases of small mistakes or a bit clearer language, changing all old instances would be desired behaviour.

Comment: If you can't trust a mod not to screw that, how do you trust us with all the other shiny buttons?

Comment: Since that was my fault, I just went ahead and fixed it, @Ben. Sorry!

Comment: The intent is to encourage you to write and edit these *in public*, @Mad, and then adding them / updating them as a team. It's less about trust than it is about recognizing that doing this right is *hard and time-consuming* - so it's worth making shortcuts a bit harder too.

Comment: @Luke, almost everything that a mod can do is reversible if challeged (or regretted).  I suspect that there's no revision-tracking here (why would there be if it wasn't intended to be edited?), so rolling back to a prior state would depend on people remembering what it was.  (I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that close reasons are built on the same infrastructure as comments, which also don't track history.)

Comment: Tracking changes is fairly trivial, @Monica - but to prevent rewriting history, we would have to tie each closed question to a specific revision of the OT reason... Which then starts to look an awful lot like what we ended up implementing except a lot more complicated.

Comment: The problem I've run into is we have a **This is a bug, report it in our tracker** which is now a broken URL, is there really no way this can be fixed?

Comment: Report it to me (or someone else on the team) and we'll fix it, @ideasman42. This is fairly rare (and a good reason to only point these at links the site's community can control) but there is a mechanism for changing them if need-be.

Comment: A note for posterity: CMs/staff can edit active custom close reasons (without necessarily having to deactivate one and create a new one). In the case of typos, this is a pretty straightforward and uncontroversial fix – so just make a post on your site's Meta reporting the issue, then have a mod [add the \[status-review\] tag to it to escalate it for staff attention](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348642/335251). For more substantial changes, though, what Shog9 said is correct – we don't want an existing close reason to be changed into something very different.