# Jobs on Technical Stack Exchange sites

Tags: discussion, announcements, jobs

Next Thursday, 18 June 2020, we’ll be making three changes to technical Stack Exchange sites that make it easier to find relevant job opportunities.

[Stack Overflow Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs) has opportunities for all technologists, and therefore it only makes sense to show these opportunities directly to the wide array of technologists that exist beyond the Stack Overflow community.

First, we will be adding a “Jobs” item to the navigation on all [technical Stack Exchange sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology), which will redirect the user off of Stack Exchange sites to [stackoverflow.com/jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs). This will allow users to more easily discover and access our job board with thousands of technologist career opportunities.

[image: site nav screenshot]

*screenshot showing "Jobs" in the main site navigation*

---

Second, we will be making adjustments to job ads on the following Technical Stack Exchange sites:

- Software Engineering
- Code Review
- Ask Ubuntu
- Unix & Linux
- WordPress Development
- Magento
- Cross Validated
- Database Administrators
- Android Enthusiasts

Up until now, job ads on these sites were restricted to users in the US, UK, and Germany. We’re expanding this globally, so that users in any location can discover job listings that are relevant to them.

---

Third, we’ll be updating the job ad designs to be consistent with those currently being shown on Stack Overflow. The ads, which currently show 2-4 listings, will now show 8 listings, meaning we’re more likely to show users a job listing of interest. As always, these job listings are targeted based on location, tech tags, and user preferences to ensure we show content that’s relevant to you.

---

Thanks to [Benjamin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1523776/benjamin-hodgson), [Juan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/472675/juan?tab=profile), [John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/57698/john-bubriski?tab=profile), [Aliza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10951714/aliza-berger?tab=profile), and Sarah for all their hard work on these initiatives!

We’re excited to better share tech jobs with the wider Stack Exchange community, and hope you will be as well. If you have questions or concerns, feel free to post them as an answer here and we’ll do our best to respond.

---

**EDIT**: for reference, here's the complete list of sites that show a "Jobs" link in the site nav:

- Stack Overflow
- Super User
- Ask Ubuntu
- Server Fault
- TeX - LaTeX
- Unix & Linux
- Ask Different
- WordPress Development
- SharePoint
- Magento
- Drupal Answers
- Database Administrators
- Code Review
- Software Engineering
- Information Security
- Blender
- Game Development
- Webmasters
- Computer Science
- Graphic Design
- User Experience
- Web Applications
- Raspberry Pi
- Ethereum
- Bitcoin
- Software Recommendations
- Arduino
- Signal Processing
- Emacs
- Data Science
- ExpressionEngine® Answers
- Network Engineering
- Craft CMS
- Programming Puzzles & Code Golf
- Theoretical Computer Science
- CiviCRM
- Software Quality Assurance & Testing
- Computational Science
- Vi and Vim
- Sitecore
- Tridion
- elementary OS
- Joomla
- Tor
- Open Data
- Robotics
- Windows Phone
- Artificial Intelligence
- Monero
- Hardware Recommendations
- DevOps
- Open Source
- Computer Graphics
- 3D Printing
- Retrocomputing
- EOS.IO
- Quantum Computing
- Internet of Things
- Stellar
- Iota
- Computer Science Educators
- Tezos
- [coming soon] Android Enthusiasts
- [coming soon] Cross Validated
- [coming soon] Salesforce
- [coming soon] Cryptography
- [coming soon] Stack Apps

Comment: Why Android Enthusiasts?  If they were looking to do Android development, surely they'd already be on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Makoto to make the ads harder to miss, of course. Can't possibly let people miss an opportunity rather than relying on them to take it upon themselves to go looking for the jobs section.

Comment: What sites are considered "technical sites" for the purposes of the "Jobs" link? You point to the technology category, but e.g. [cs.se], [cstheory.se] and [stats.se] are not in that category, but do have the "Jobs" link. I understand that the existing category is not used as a basis for your campaign, but it might be helpful to mention that this category does not list all sites with this link.

Comment: @Discretelizard you're right, it doesn't exactly follow the Technology category on SE. We filtered out the language-specific sites, meta, and sites that weren't related to the technologist roles we have listed on Jobs today (e.g. mathematica, space exploration, sound design). We also included sites from other categories that are closely related (e.g. computer science, artificial intelligence). And while prepping this response, we actually found a handful of sites we missed! I've updated the post to include a full list of sites that show the "Jobs" link for reference. Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: @PuneetMulchandani Thanks for providing a full list.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Screenshot of the new Jobs link in the left side menu]

So this is now live.

Why does it go to site.stackexchange.com/jobs as if there were particular jobs for that site? (There doesn't seem to be any particular filter once your browser follows the redirects.)

Why is it in the middle of other site links? Could you move it so that it would be in its own section like it is on SO? Or at least put it after the site links with a gap between them. It's not like you're lacking space in the side bar!

[image: Screenshot of how the Jobs link appears on Stack Overflow]

Comment: Easier to track the clicks when the link is relative, I think. They just track the click and redirect. As for why in the middle of the other links, no idea.