# SoundCloud embeds broken on 'Music: Practice & Theory'

Tags: bug, soundcloud, embedding

Embedded links for [SoundCloud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SoundCloud) were added in 2011, *[YouTube and SoundCloud embedding is now enabled](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245/youtube-and-soundcloud-embedding-is-now-enabled)*, briefly broken when transitioning to HTTPS, *[https for SoundCloud](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/980/https-for-soundcloud)*, and then fixed again.

Since early 2021 these all seem to have broken again.
I raised the issue on Music Meta—*[Soundcloud embedding - new issues?](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3643/soundcloud-embedding-new-issues)* —but this seems to have attracted little attention, so I'm bringing it to main meta to see if I can get it some love.

Comment: I've added the status-review tag to the question on Music meta - In future, please flag for moderator attention and ask them to status-review tag the question so that it is brought to our attention - full guidance on this policy can be found here - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348642/what-posts-should-be-escalated-to-staff-using-status-review-and-how-do-i-esca

Comment: I really cannot be expected to know the full policy procedure for every issue across entire site, nor even that there IS one. I wouldn't have had any idea that policy guidance existed if you hadn't linked it, let alone how to find it. Thank you for adding the flag, but regular users cannot be expected to know how this all works.

Comment: Still… it did as intended - raised awareness. ;)