# Which questions are eligible for tagging [status-review] if latest available list is outdated?

Tags: support, stack-exchange-team, moderator-tags

The question [What posts should be escalated to staff using [status-review], and how do I escalate them?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348642/339911) has a list of posts which should be taken into account before escalating bug or feature-request to the staff level by adding [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag.

Currently (July 12, 2023) the latest (accepted) [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/388089/339911) is outdated since it covers time range April-June 2023.

In such situation what questions are eligible for tagging [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)? Could we rely on accepted answer even when dates went away until further notice, or this process should be considered stopped since answer is outdated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I aim to post the stats for the previous quarter as well as the targets and guidance for the upcoming one as early as possible at the beginning of any given quarter. Due to various reasons, however, these can sometimes get delayed a bit (in fact, some times they've been delayed a lot). In this case, the delay is due to the fact that we have to update the reporting of stats, given we proposed adjusting the targets last quarter to report on a single response metric — this is being actively worked on.

With all of that being said, though, **the process should be considered in effect, unless a staff member has announced that it has been retired**. The post is linked to from various sources, including mod help center articles, so if it ever gets retired a clean up and proper announcement are in order.

**In cases where the post hasn't been updated in a timely fashion, you can either just keep following the guidance presented in the currently accepted answer or wait for a bit longer for it to be updated** (and potentially post a comment in the accepted answer asking someone for a time estimate for that).

Comment: I've had a flag declined because I did exactly this, following the latest advice even though it was outdated, and then the answer got updated to remove the topic of the request I was trying to escalate before the moderator got around to processing my flag. The decline message explicitly stated that the subsequent edit was the reason for the flag getting declined. Because the moderator decided to decline it rather than deeming it helpful without action, the implication is that either I shouldn't flag based on older topics or that the onus is on me to notice and retract the flag. Which is it?

Comment: I don't see any of your flags surrounding this process that have been declined since June 2021. The flag you're likely referring to dates back to November 2020, when you flagged a post for escalation, the guidance for that quarter was posted around 7h later, and the flag was declined 2 days afterwards — I don't think it's unreasonable for that flag to have been declined, given the circumstances, and the guidance provided in this answer stands.