# Edge point for a diamond used as a popover arrow in tooltips should be slightly shifted

Tags: bug, design, tooltips

Recently I learned that a diamond shape is used for imitation of tooltip popover arrow:

> [image]

<sub>Animation was made on [Suspicious voting tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/391806/339911) page</sub>

Looks like that to make an imitation more natural the edge position of a diamond relative to the bubble of tooltip should be slightly changed to prevent exit the internal part of the diamond beyond bubble boundaries.

One more thing here is that diamond boundaries are visible when the diamond is below the bubble:

> [image]

And doesn't visible if the diamond at the top:

> [image]

<sub>Latter two images were taken user flagged posts page, e.g. [mine own](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/flagged-posts/176217).</sub>

Comment: I've also noticed (and seen reports of) similar issues with this type of element in other parts of the UI (e.g. the "All"/"Unread" filter for the inbox), so I don't think it's an issue unique to specific mod tools. (Though it may be more noticeable in recently updated mod tool pages that now make use of this element.)

Comment: While this may be a legitimate UI bug, I am downvoting this because IMHO, this type of "pixel-perfect" UI bug is a complete waste of engineering resources, and should be the lowest priority.

Comment: This appears to be largely an issue with [popper.js](https://popper.js.org/) and how it calculates offsets for the arrow element and the popover itself. Popper.js is what Stacks uses to manage their [popover elements](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/popovers/) and not something in SE's control.

Comment: I'm not sure about the second part, the arrow is always rendered on top of the popover regardless of where the popover is positioned. It's possible that the box shadow below the popover is making the arrow somewhat more visible when positioned above the toggle, but if you look close enough you can definitely see it regardless of where it's positioned. You can observe [this even on the demo page](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/popovers/#manual-examples) and it's even more clear if you [change the arrow color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6cFY.png).

Comment: @AMtwo voting means nothing for prioritizing bugs inside SE

Comment: @αλεχολυτ I know how bugs are prioritized internally, since I am former staff.   Bug reports take time for internal review, prioritization, etc. Regardless of what factors make up that prioritization, I think these bugs are wasting time for the staff that have to handle these. Time better spent fixing more significant bugs.